# Adding "Subtitle" fields in All wordpress available widgets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there way to hook "Sub title" fields After Widget Title fields in all wordpress available fields? , then show it after widget title

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any solutions for using a hook to work around this, but there are plugins like **[DP Widgets Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dp-widgets-plus/)**.